# Returning 2 actions in 1 effect using Redux in Angular 8

Tags: angular, redux

I'm trying to return two actions in one simple effect using Redux in Angular 8, but I'm unable. I tried dispatching one action and returning the other one, but doesn't work. This is what I need to do:

```
@Effect()
createOrderRemake$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(orderRemakeActions.OrderRemakeActitonTypes.CreateOrderRemake),
  mergeMap((action: orderRemakeActions.CreateOrderRemake) => {
    return this.orderRemakeService.createOrderRemake(action.payload).pipe(
      map((payload: OrderRemake) => {
        if (payload !== null) {        
          return new orderRemakeActions.CreateOrderRemakeSuccess(orderRemake);
          return new orderPlannedActions.SetInfoModal(true); // UNREACHABLE
        } else {
          return new orderRemakeActions.CreateOrderRemakeFail('ERROR in CreateOrderRemake effect.');
          return new orderPlannedActions.SetInfoModal(true); // UNREACHABLE
        }
      }),
      catchError(err => of(new orderRemakeActions.CreateOrderRemakeFail(err)))
      );
    }
  )
);
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `map` operator, witch by nature spawns 1 event for 1 event that it gets. insead I would propose you to use other mapping operators(all of them will work the same in your case). for example fix with the help of `mergeMap`:

```ts
 mergeMap((payload: OrderRemake) => {
        if (payload !== null) {        
          return [
           new orderRemakeActions.CreateOrderRemakeSuccess(orderRemake),
           new orderPlannedActions.SetInfoModal(true)
         ]; // now will emit 2 of these actions
        } else {
          return [new orderRemakeActions.CreateOrderRemakeFail('ERROR in CreateOrderRemake effect.'),
          new orderPlannedActions.SetInfoModal(true)];
        }
      })
```